# Saving the User Info in session in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, direct-line-botframework

I have developed chat bot with C#
Need to show **different greeting message**,  on User using the chatbot for second time with in a day.
**If user is using the chatbot for first time in a day, need to show "Hi, how can I help You" greeting message. second time on using chatbot need to show "Welcome back 'Username', how can I help you" message.**

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

By default Bots are stateless. The state and storage features of the Bot Framework SDK allow you to manage the state of your bot. There is documentation available in this context - [Save user and conversation data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-state?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5002040)

Here is some code that meets your requirement.

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // Get the state properties from the turn context.

    var conversationStateAccessors =  _conversationState.CreateProperty<ConversationData>(nameof(ConversationData));
    var conversationData = await conversationStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new ConversationData());

    var userStateAccessors = _userState.CreateProperty<UserProfile>(nameof(UserProfile));
    var userProfile = await userStateAccessors.GetAsync(turnContext, () => new UserProfile());

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Name))
    {
        // First time around this is set to false, so we will prompt user for name.
        if (conversationData.PromptedUserForName)
        {
            // Set the name to what the user provided.
            userProfile.Name = turnContext.Activity.Text?.Trim();

            // Acknowledge that we got their name.
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Thanks {userProfile.Name}. To see conversation data, type anything.");

            // Reset the flag to allow the bot to go through the cycle again.
            conversationData.PromptedUserForName = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // Prompt the user for their name.
            await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"What is your name?");

            // Set the flag to true, so we don't prompt in the next turn.
            conversationData.PromptedUserForName = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Add message details to the conversation data.
        // Convert saved Timestamp to local DateTimeOffset, then to string for display.
        var messageTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset) turnContext.Activity.Timestamp;
        var localMessageTime = messageTimeOffset.ToLocalTime();
        conversationData.Timestamp = localMessageTime.ToString();
        conversationData.ChannelId = turnContext.Activity.ChannelId.ToString();

        // Display state data.
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"{userProfile.Name} sent: {turnContext.Activity.Text}");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Message received at: {conversationData.Timestamp}");
        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync($"Message received from: {conversationData.ChannelId}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Second time User name is not available in user profile

Comment: How to get userstate information second time for same user in same channel. It is showing null on starting new conversation

Comment: If you're following the documentation, it is using the InMemoryData store. If you like to persist, you need to use SQL Server or Azure Table Storage. Otherwise, if you restart the bot, it won't persist the data.

Comment: Can you please share me how to get userata from InMemoryData store.
I have tried to get user info from User State but it showing null for second conversation.
I have followed the same as in document.

Comment: Check out this - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/45.state-management/Startup.cs#L24 You can find implementation of Blob Storage and Cosmos DB